# Loop not changing values in dataframe - R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a loop that works fine, but the output is only returned in console, dataframe remains unmodified.

- a the end of the loop the head(data) is returned in the console, producing the expected values in the expected column
- however, this is not changed in the original dataframe, where I want the values to appear (printing the head(data) now gives me the original values, not the new ones created by the loop)

Sample code:

```
df <- cbind(x,y)
myfun <- function(z){
    counter <- 0
    for (i in 1:z) {
    counter <- 1 + counter
        for (j in 1:5) {
        counter <- 1 + counter
            if (condition_a){
                df[counter,2] <- 0
            }
            if (condition_b){
                df[counter,2] <- 1
            }
        }
    }
    return(head(df))
    newdf <- df[,2]
}
```

What am I missing?

The values are of class int, should this matter?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. See [ask]

Comment: you're light on the details..need to include a reproducible example and your code.

Comment: Please add your data sets, explain what are you trying to do and provide desired output. We could close this off by solving your local issue by telling to use something like `<<-`, but I believe your whole approach is incorrect and this could be solved much more easily without all these unnecessary loops and certainly without using `<<-`

Comment: Probably I am too new to know this, if you could provide tips I would be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to change something outside of a function then you could use `df[counter,2] <<- 1` which will change the value of `df` outside of your function.

However, this isn't great practice as every time you run the function you will end up with a change in your `df` data frame. Instead look at returning values. Also, there's probably some simplification you can do instead of your loops to make your code run quicker. I've attached an example to show you how you would do what you wanted to do anyway.

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3)
y <- c(0, 1, 2, 3)

df <- data.frame(x, y)     

a<-function(){
 df[,2] <<- c(0, 0, 0, 0) 
}

b<-function(){
  df[,2] <- c(0, 0, 0, 0) 
}

b()

df

a()

df
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked!